# Emacs customization

Tags: c++, python, emacs, customization

I'm new to the whole Emacs thing, and one of the things that gets me is that out-of-the-box Emacs doesn't keep you within blocks when programming. I program in mostly Python and C++ and hitting enter sends the cursor back to column 1 on a new line rather than keeping you in the block you're working in. I managed to find this:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda () (define-key python-mode-map "\C-m" 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Which binds the enter key to newline-and-indent in Python mode, but how do I extend this to cover C/C++ mode too?

Comment: A siden note: emacs has this bound on C-j by default.

Comment: That's true, but it's not that easy getting used to C-j after a lifetime of hitting ENTER and getting the same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is from my init.el for xemacs, it might or might not work for emacs:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      '(lambda () 
         (define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))
```